# Laravel 5.1 Create table from controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

This is the situation: I have a list of user, this user are associate to a company and those companies are associate to a group. Each user can create a client who is associate to the user and the company in which the user belong. For the moment, all my client are in the same database table. But I want to have a clients table for each company.

I'm looking for the right way to create a clients table when i create a company. Example, when I create company A, the controller add the row A in the companies table then retrieve the company_id and create clients_id table. For now, I tried this:

```
    public function storeCompany(Request $request)
{
    $company= new Company;
    $company-> group_id     = Request::get('group_id');
    $company-> company_name  = Request::get('company_name');
    $company-> phone        = Request::get('phone');
    $company-> save();
    $company_id = DB::table('companies')->where('company_name',$company->company_name)->first();
    Schema::create('clients_'.$company_id, function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('columntest');
    });
    return redirect('admin/managecompany');
}
```

I added this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
```

But I got this error :

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Schema' not found
```

Finally, I am trying to find an issue for my error and I want to know if there is an option to make it easier or any other suggestion to do it in a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: You really _don’t_ want a table per company.

Comment: `\Schema` should solve that error. Namespacing issue. That being said, listen to the advice being given here... One table per company doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain me why? There is my reasons:
The same client can be added to many companies. But a company can't add the same client twice. A client can have more then one transaction associate to it. With duplicate table for each comapny, I am able to make the column email from client unique and don't allow user from company A to add this client twice and alert his director. But user from company B can add it.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I want to know why and what is the alternative?

Comment: @ElieMorin The "correct" way to do this is to have a pivot table that joins clients to a company. So you will have a `client` table, a `company` table, and a `company_clients` table. The `company_clients` table will have entries that connect the `company_id` to the `client_id`. Here is the Laravel documentation on this sort of relationship: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. [Here is the Laravel documentation on this sort of relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). The ->belongsToMany() function allows you specify the joining table (`company_clients`).

Answer (score 0):

Some one put this and deleted his comment:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema as Schema;
```

@Tim Lewis said it too. That solved my problem. But when I tested it, I faced another problem. I was not creating a model, so I was unable to add row using

```
$client = new Client;
```

This is what I've done:

Firstly, I change the function storeCompany to this:

```
    public function storeCompany(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company;
    $company -> group_id     = Request::get('group_id');
    $company -> company_name  = Request::get('company_name');
    $company -> phone        = Request::get('phone');
    $company -> save();

    $company = DB::table('companys')->where('company_name',$company->company_name)->first();
    $company_id = $company -> id;

    Log::info('Lancement de la création des tables @ ' . \Carbon\Carbon::now());
    for ($i=1; $i <6; $i++) {
        if ($i == 1 ) {$out = shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\newCompanyTable.bat" "D0" "D'.$company_id.'"');}
        if ($i == 2 ) {$out = shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\newCompanyTable.bat" "d0" "d'.$company_id.'"');}
        if ($i == 3 ) {$out = shell_exec('C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\newCompanyTable.bat');}
        if ($i == 4 ) {$out = shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction && php artisan migrate');}
        if ($i == 5 ) {$out = shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\newCompanyTable.bat" "D'.$company_id.'" "D0"');}
        if ($i == 6 ) {$out = shell_exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\newCompanyTable.bat" "d'.$company_id.'" "d0"');}
        Log::info($out);
    }
    return redirect('admin/managecompany');
}
```

Secondly, I created this .bat file:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app && copy "Client.php" "D0client.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app && copy "Transaction.php" "D0transaction.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app && copy "Job.php" "D0job.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app && copy "Log.php" "D0log.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations && copy "2015_11_03_153725_create_clients_table.php" "2015_11_03_153725_create_d0clients_table.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations && copy "2015_11_03_185333_create_transactions_table.php" "2015_11_03_185333_create_d0transactions_table.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations && copy "2015_12_01_024822_create_jobs_table.php" "2015_12_01_024822_create_d0jobs_table.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations && copy "2015_12_01_024854_create_logs_table.php" "2015_12_01_024854_create_d0logs_table.php"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0client.php" "Client" "D0client"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0transaction.php" "Transaction" "D0transaction"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0job.php" "Job" "D0job"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0log.php" "Log" "D0log"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0client.php" "clients" "d0clients"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0transaction.php" "transactions" "d0transactions"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0job.php" "jobs" "d0jobs"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\app\d0log.php" "logs" "d0logs"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_11_03_153725_create_d0clients_table.php" "clients" "d0clients"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_11_03_185333_create_d0transactions_table.php" "transactions" "d0transactions"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_12_01_024822_create_d0jobs_table.php" "jobs" "d0jobs"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_12_01_024854_create_d0logs_table.php" "logs" "d0logs"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_11_03_153725_create_d0clients_table.php" "CreateClientsTable" "CreateD0clientsTable"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_11_03_185333_create_d0transactions_table.php" "CreateTransactionsTable" "CreateD0transactionsTable"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_12_01_024822_create_d0jobs_table.php" "CreateJobsTable" "CreateD0jobsTable"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site && cscript replace.vbs "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction\database\migrations\2015_12_01_024854_create_d0logs_table.php" "CreateLogsTable" "CreateD0logsTable"
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\site\lastaction && composer dump
```

So now, when I add a new Company, the server get this company_id then modify the .bat file who copy base migration and model to match the new company. After this it launch the php artisan migrate.

Now, users can add data to the client/transaction table of their company without interacting with other companies tables.

Maybe I'm wrong doing this... But it work to do what I need. If you have any suggest, say/write it!